# Empty Log-Files in JBoss EAP 6.4.4 (Logging-Profiles)

Tags: java, logging, jboss

i have 3 applications/wars which will be deployed on one JBoss EAP 6.4.4. and i need seperate log-files for each application. so i tried the following steps [(as seen in this doku)](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles):

I. i added logging profiles to the MANIFEST.MF:

> \a.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF contains "Logging-Profile: aProfile"
>   \s.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF contains "Logging-Profile: sProfile"
>   \t.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF contains "Logging-Profile: tProfile"

II. i added the following logging subsystem to the standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>
  <!-- ... -->
  <root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
    </handlers>
  </root-logger>
  <logging-profiles>
    <logging-profile name="aProfile">
      <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] %m  (%X{LogContext})%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="a.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
      </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
      <root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
          <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
      </root-logger>
    </logging-profile>
    <logging-profile name="sProfile">
      <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] %m  (%X{LogContext})%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="s.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
      </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
      <root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
          <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
      </root-logger>
    </logging-profile>
    <logging-profile name="tProfile">
      <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] %m  (%X{LogContext})%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="t.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
      </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
      <root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
          <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
      </root-logger>
    </logging-profile>
  </logging-profiles>
</subsystem>
```

=> all 3 log-files are created on startup, but only 't.log' and the console show the log-entries - 'a.log' and 's.log' remain empty. i tried several modifications (e.g. changed Logging-Profile of s.war to tProfile etc.), in the end only 't.log' works as expected.

=> what am i doing wrong?

(note: a.war, s.war and t.war use some other internal projects/jars with similar package names, so logger categories are probably no option here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by removing the log4j.jar (and other unnecessary jars) from WEB-INF/lib

steps to fix it:

- remove all (manually added) Java Build Path Entries from Project > Properties > Deployment Assembly
- Project-Menu > Clean
- Project > Maven > Disable Maven Nature
- Project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project
- check that Project > Java Build Path > Libraries contains Maven Dependencies
- Project-Menu > Clean
- check that there is no log4j.jar in WEB-INF\lib